# Smooth domain and compact sets

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $O\subset M$ is an open domain and $K\subset O$ is some compact set. I am wondering if there always exists an open domain $D$ in $M$ with smooth boundary and such that $K\subset D\subset O$? Unfortunately I do not know how to approach this problem. Does anyone have an idea?

Best wishes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. Here's one way to do it.

Let $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth bump function that is identically equal to $1$ on $K$ and supported in $O$. (The existence of such a function can be proved easily using a partition of unity; see, e.g., Proposition 2.25 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd ed.) By [Sard's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), there is a number $c\in (0,1)$ that is a regular value of $f$, and then the set $f^{-1}([c,1])$ is a domain with smooth boundary containing $K$ and contained in $O$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your approach is fascinating. But I am concerned about the following issue. I would like to choose the domain (=open & connected set) $D$ in such a way that the topological boundary $\partial D$ becomes a smooth manifold. Now in your proof the set $f^{-1}(c,\infty) $ is open and the set $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth manifold contained in the (topological) boundary of $D$. As far as I know, it can happen that $f^{-1}(c)$ does not equal the full boundary of $D$. Is it possible to force the top. boundary to coincide with $f^{-1}(c)$ somehow?

Comment: Yes, the topological boundary of $D$ is the same as its manifold boundary. See Propositions 5.46 and 5.47 in _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_.